# Spilled coffee on my puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language, geography

Some time ago I created a nice simple puzzle. It's a horizontal word grid with 22 letters and nine clues. However, I spilled some coffee on my notes and can no longer remember what numbers I wanted to put in clues 1 and 4. Can you help me out?

> [image]
>
> 1. *(illegible)* in hexadecimal
> 2. furry red monster
> 3. musical cookware
> 4. *(illegible)* in hexadecimal
> 5. software documentation
> 6. romance water
> 7. something with quiero
> 8. female relative
> 9. megacity

Comment: Do any of the clues overlap, i.e. is it certain that clue 1 is 1 letter long, and clue 2 is 4 letters long?

Comment: @AHKieran No overlap, #1 is one letter etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The missing clues are

> 1. **11** in hexadecimal
>  4. **10** in hexadecimal

After filling the rest of the clues (and figuring out better words for 5, 6, and 9 particularly), you get

> [image]

If you now fill in the mystery clues, you get

> [image]

Which finally fits the somewhat surprising tags by listing

> overlapping Middle American capital cities.

Particularly, the ones listed are

> * Belmopan, the capital of Belize
>  * Panama, the capital of Panama
>  * Managua, the capital of Nicaragua, and
>  * Guatemala, the capital of Guatemala

Answer (score 4):

Clues:

> (illegible) in hexadecimal - **E** (a guess, as Hex characters are A-F)
>  furry red monster - **ELMO**
>  musical cookware - **PAN**
>  (illegible) in hexadecimal - **D** (a guess, as above)
>  software documentation - **DOC** (As in .doc)
>  romance water - **TORA**?? (Can only think of *The Shape of Water* although that's Del *Toro*)
>  something with quiero - **TE** ("te quiero", Spanish for "I love you")
>  female relative - **MA** (short for Mother)
>  megacity - **NY** (New York)

Which can also be broken to read as:

> EEL MOP AND DOCTORATE MANY

So your missing letters are:

> E and D

Answer (score 3):

Are the missing answers:

> E and D

And therefore the clues:

> *"14 in hex"* and *"13 in hex"*

Reasoning:

> I only solved half the clues, but got ELMO for clue 2, and PAN for clue 3.
>  When I put them together I noticed that the word MOP was created in between them.
>  I assumed the single digit of hex would be a letter to match the rest, and so that limited me to A through F.
>  I therefore deduced that the first letter would combine with the first few letters of ELMO, and therefor would be E to create EEL.
>  And also that the last letters of PAN would form another word with the answer to clue 4, and in choosing D, they make AND.
>  I assume there is a similar connection between the other words, but I haven't figured them out yet apart from:

Reasoning continued: (**Edited to include @Astralbee 's solutions, credit to them**)

> 5 being DOC (.doc)
>  6 being TORO (for Guillermo Del Toro, creater of *The Shape of Water*)
>  7 being TE (te quiero being a spanish phrase *"I Love You"*)
>  8 being MA (term for mother)
>  9 perhaps being NY for New York
>  This creates the whole line EELMOPANDDOCTOROTEMANY which contains the following words:
>  **EEL, ELMO, MOP, PAN, AND, DOC, OCTO, DOCTOR, ROT, TEMA (a city in Ghana), MANY, and ANY.**